# Does the key have a hash table map to a memory location?

Tags: java, hash, dictionary

When you insert items in a hash, does the key get encoded to a physical memory space, hence the very fast lookup times? i.e constant lookup times.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has near constant look up times (provided you have a trivial amount of collisions) by using an array of `Entry` references.

Java doesn't manipulate address locations directly as these can be changed by the [GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a hash table is to store the items in an array, with the index being computed very fast from the key (in java's `Hashtable` the `hashcode()` method of the key is called and it's used to get the index (modulo the length of the table)).

When the table isn't too full, you have few elements (chained) in this table at this index. Looking for the element is simply comparing their keys to the passed key.

So it's constant time for an almost empty table, but a little longer when the table gets full, because the collisions mean you have more comparisons to make.